# How to create an exclusion filter set in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am working in Tableau and trying to figure out how to create a filter exclusion.  For example I have the following fields.

Hospital    CallType    CallDate

I want to filter out all hospitals where one of the Calls has a call type of ColdCall and a Call DateBetween X and Y.

I can do this easily in SQL but don't have access to this data in the SQL Database.  It would be the following:

```
Select
Hospital
,CallType
,CallDate
Into
#TempTable
From
Database

Select
Hospital
,CallType
,CallDate
Into
#ExclusionTable
From
Database
Where
CallType = 'Cold'
and
CallDate Between X and Y

Select
Hospital
,CallType
,CallDate
From
#TempTable
Where
Hospital not in
(Select
Hospital
From
#ExclusionTable)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. Create a calculated field Filter:

```
IF CallType = "Cold" AND CallDate < X AND CallDate > Y
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Then drag Hospital to filter, go to Condition tab, select by field, get your Filter field, use sum > 0. It will filter out any hospital that have at least one call with your conditions (because all the calls that don't meet will be zero, and if at least one is not zero, the sum will be over 0)

For X and Y, I'd create parameters. It's easier (and safer) than trying to write the dates directly on the field. And you can manipulate then more easily too